# Create custom log file magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, log

for 2.4.2 below code working

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message') 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

for 2.4.2 above code working

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Above solution not working in Magento 2.4.3 version anybody have an idea for the same

For 2.4.3?

Comment: You need to do something like this to achieve this.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/log/custom-logger-handler.html

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 8):

the custom log file created using the below code

for Magento 2.4.2 before version use this

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message') 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

for Magento 2.4.2 or after version use this

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

for Magento 2.4.3 version use this

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Comment: Hold on, why is 2.4.3 still using Zend?

Answer (score 3):

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the correct way to create log file

`magento/app/code/vendorname/modulename/etc/di.xml`

```
<!-- start logger-->

    <virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Log\Handler" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">/var/log/custom_logger_name.log</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Log\Logger" type="Monolog\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Vendor::ModuleName</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Log\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ClassWhereNeedToInjectCustomLogger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Log\Logger</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

<!-- end logger-->
```

On the constructor of this class `Magento\app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ClassWhereNeedToInjectCustomLogger` inject `Psr\LoggerInteface` on the constructor and use the methods, it will write on your new file log.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Execute below command to include log library into the `vendor/laminas` if not there.

This has been removed from 2.4.3.

For Magento 2.4.3 version, execute this - `composer require laminas/laminas-log -vvv`

Comment: Thank you @sandip, but Magento has removed this module in version 2.4.3 so something reason behind it. so we need to find out another solution instead of adding again laminas log.